# How to create Personality quiz page design like screenshot i am attaching?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

How to create Personality quiz page like screenshot i am attaching? I need the design just like screenshot in html, CSS or WordPress please. Also attaching the reference link for design: website.https://www.16personalities.com/free-personality-test
Thank you
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. question create with p/label/div tag.
2. code sample like below,

```html
 <p>Seeing other people cry can easily make.......</p>
  <span><b>Agree</b></span>
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="value1"> Value 1
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="value2"> Value 2
  <input type="radio" name="test" value="value3"> Value 3
  <span><b>Disagree</b></span>
```

3. make some database like mysql, pass mysql_connect and loop data with above html
4. in database also store column like selected radio button.

Comment: Thank you but i need the design Sir.

Comment: is design same as your pic and why use 6-7 radio

Comment: Actually i am learning and new, can you please give me any reference or something to start?

Comment: w3school, tutorialspoint , udemy courses are freely available online to read .  1)  for radio button https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp  2) you can also try https://codepen.io/AngelaVelasquez/pen/DGeErL